# Spawn-fcgi not working on windows

Tags: spawn-fcgi

I have build spawn-fcgi for windows using cygwin from source code available here : https://github.com/lighttpd/spawn-fcgi

And I'm trying to run mapserver using spawn-fcgi. In log file it gives **spawn-fcgi: child spawned successfully: PID: 4920** but when i'm looking for process with this PID, there is no process.

I have [hello_world](http://chriswu.me/blog/writing-hello-world-in-fcgi-with-c-plus-plus/) example to test spawn-fcgi but this is also not working.